# Receiving Empty set (0.00 sec) when wanting to see created table

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a table called person in a created database called hr using the follow code

```
CREATE TABLE person (
-> person_id INT(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
-> first_name VARCHAR(25),
-> last_name VARCHAR(25),
-> gender VARCHAR(1),
-> age INT(8),
-> eye_color VARCHAR(25),
-> PRIMARY KEY(person_id)
-> ) auto_increment=1;
```

I ran this code using mysql> SELECT * FROM person;, and now I want to see this table but I get Empty set (0.00 sec).

I cannot figure why the table wont show...

Comment: The table has no rows.  Hence you get an exmpty set.

Comment: Oh god seriously!! OK thank you!! I am new to this, my apologies for the silly question...

Comment: For a little more info: using `desc person;` will show you the structure of the table.